# Explaining Grouping in Pandas in a way similar to the group function in dyplr in R

Tags: python, r, pandas, pandas-groupby

Simple question that I could not find an answer for:

Why when we group a panda df by a varaibel and then we sort the result why dont we see the grouped rosw togather like the case in the group function dplyr in R?

For examaple, I have this data frame:

```
Item      Type    Price 
 A         1       22
 B         1       58
 C         1       33
 A         2       80
 A         3       50
 B         2       98
 C         3       63
 B         5        8
```

If we group by `item` and then sort by `Price`, we should see the 'A's togather, 'B's togather, and the two 'C's togather where each of these three groups are sorted. How can we accomplish this in python?

I tried this:

```
df.groupby('Item').sort_values(['Price']) # This is not right becuase we can not access the sort function on the grouped by object

df.sort_values('Price').groupby(['Item']) # This does part of the job, but I wnder why I can not see the groupped items togather?
```

The output is expected to look like this:

```
Item      Type    Price 
 A         2       80 
 A         3       50    
 A         1       22
 B         2       98
 B         1       58
 B         5        8
 C         3       63
 C         1       33
```

Comment: can you give us an example of your expected output? I'm confused because you seem to use "sorted" and "grouped" interchangeably.

Comment: You need to illustrate all points with data as previous comments kindly ask. Most pandas folks probably do not know what dplyr's `groupby` looks like. And for that matter they may not be versed in R.

Comment: No I am not using them interchangably, I am grouping and then sorting. Group by 'x' and sort by 'y'. I want to have the output as a data frame grouped by items and sorted by price.

Comment: @owise What have you tried that isn't working? And are you saying group (aggregate) on Item, then sort on Price? Or sort on Item, then sort on Price? This is where we are completely unclear.

Comment: I editted my question and I added what I tried

Comment: @owise Without you producing the expected output I don't understand how you could possibly expect us to figure it out. Good luck.

Comment: @Andrew L I editted the question accordinlgy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your output, you can use `df.sort_values`:

```
In [783]: df.sort_values(['Item', 'Price'],  ascending=[True, False])
Out[783]: 
  Item  Type  Price
3    A     2     80
4    A     3     50
0    A     1     22
5    B     2     98
1    B     1     58
7    B     5      8
6    C     3     63
2    C     1     33
```

A groupby is not needed.